# HTTPS Working Fine, but HTTP Shows Default Apache page

Tags: apache2

Everything was working fine but suddenly i noticed that my website is not working fine.

When I try to visit my website over HTTPS, everything is working fine but when I try to access website over HTTP, it shows default apache page instead of website.

I am facing this issue across all of my websites on my server.